# Trying to show the product of two EditTexts as a TextView in another activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-edittext

I am having a ton of trouble passing the product of two EditTexts to a TextView in another activity. Here is my code for MainActivity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button1: Button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
        val editText1: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText1)
        val editText2: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText2)
        val firstNumber = editText1.toString().toInt()
        val secondNumber = editText2.toString().toInt()
        val product = firstNumber * secondNumber

        button1.setOnClickListener{

            val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("RESULT_PRODUCT", product)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for Activity2:

```
class Activity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)

        val product = intent.getIntExtra("RESULT_SUM", 0)
        textView1.text = product.toString()
    }
}
```

I am relatively new to Kotlin and Android Studio but this has caused crashes left and right.

Comment: Declare product variable type Integer

val product:Int = firstNumber * secondNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all,** You have to calculate the `product` inside `OnClickListener` to get correct result.

```
button1.setOnClickListener{

    val firstNumber = editText1.text.toString().trim()
    val secondNumber = editText2.text.toString().trim()

    if(!(firstNumber.isEmpty() or secondNumber.isEmpty())) {
        val product = firstNumber.toInt() * secondNumber.toInt()

        val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("RESULT_PRODUCT", product)
        startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        //Show messages
    }
}
```

**And then** you have to use the exact key **RESULT_PRODUCT** that you use in your activity to pass data through `intent`

```
val product = intent.getIntExtra("RESULT_PRODUCT", 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. After making your edits I receive an error in MainActivity:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{e50e19d VFED..CL. ........ 405,24-1035,160 #7f070036 app:id/editText1}".

This has been an error I have been receiving since before the edit.

Comment: Check the update. You have to get text from `EditText` like `editText1.text.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing "RESULT_PRODUCT" from MainActivity but getting "RESULT_SUM" in your Activity2. You should use `intent.getIntExtra("RESULT_PRODUCT", 0)` in you second activity.